# How do I remove all CSS styles for an element without a Class or ID?

Tags: html, css

I have 5 buttons **without** any Class or ID. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<button>Btn1</button>
<button>Btn2</button>
<button>Btn3</button> <!-- I don't want this elem to get the CSS styles -->
<button>Btn4</button>
<button>Btn5</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #12aeef;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #888888;
}
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PgQw/).

How can I make the 3rd element not get the CSS styles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an alternative to Mihai's answer, if you'd like to be able to use it on more than element, add a `class` to any appropriate `button`:

```
<button class="nostyle">
```

Then in your CSS, simply change `button` to `button:not(.nostyle)`.

That's it! ...what, you were expecting more work?

Here's the updated code:

```css
button:not(.nostyle) {
    width: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #12aeef;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px #888888;
}
```

```html
<button>Btn1</button>
<button>Btn2</button>
<button class="nostyle">Btn3</button>
<button>Btn4</button>
<button>Btn5</button>
```

Comment: This solution will not work for IE8 and IE7 as they do not support the :not selector.

Comment: i don't think it is really necessary to use http://selectivizr.com/ that would be adding 4.75kb to the page just to remove styles from one button. if you can add that script tag to the page then surely you can add a class or link to a js file and add a class with js. that would save you like 5kb

Comment: @Connor Maybe when [640kb ought to be enough for anybody](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9101699/The_640K_quote_won_t_go_away_but_did_Gates_really_say_it_), this might've been an issue. Now, not so much.

Comment: @Danny I agree that micro-optimization within the application is not a good thing. On the other hand where does it stop? Should we propose using WordPress and adding a selectivizr WordPress Plugin for convenience' sake?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to start adding plugins when when this can be achieved by other means. What if this were to be used in a mobile environment?

Comment: @jezzipin Then it would be supported: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/mobile.html

Comment: Regardless it's a bad idea to add plugins unless they serve any real purpose or add to the functionality

Answer (score 4):

## Abusing OP' wording:

We want to *remove styling* (i.e.: the styling was already applied to the element and we want it removed) without any Classes or ID (i.e.: HTML must not be touched).

### First and foremost how do we "reset" some CSS properties that have already been inherited by an element?

This requires some knowledge of the defaults ex.:

```
width: auto; // the default for sizes is auto
```

But also some investigation regarding the rest of your css because you may have some reset stylesheet included into your project which tells all elements everywhere to have behave diferently (this usually applies to paddings / margins / borders etc.).

### Now that we know how to "reset" the CSS properties we need to identify the element to which we apply this "reset".

We can use `:nth-child()`, a CSS3 pseudo selector that finds child elements which ocupy the nth offset within the parent regardless of element type.

### Put it together and we have:

```
button:nth-child(3) {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    /* ... */
}
```

## Ignoring OP' wording but offering a better solution:

Try Connors last fiddle for the most efficience and elegance, or his first for full compatibility.

Comment: care to explain what `nth-child();` is?

Comment: The nth-child(3) essentially references the third occurance of <button> in the html. Again this is not supported by IE8 and below.

Comment: @jezzipin he was encouraging me to enhance my answer not asking for more info for himself, he knows what nth-child does (IMHO so does OP).

Comment: Well now this is what you call a detailed post

Comment: As I said, I like to give a useful answer (based on what I think OP' independence level and abilities are). Later on I like to enhance my answer for the benefit of (future) others. That way I achieve both goals: making OP work / think for it as well as helping (future) others.

Answer (score 3):

i don't think there is a cross browser way to do this in css without `class` or `id` so For Cross Browser Compatability you can do something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <button>text 1</button>
    <button>text 2</button>
    <div class="no-style">
        <button>text 3</button>
    </div>
    <button>text 4</button>
    <button>text 5</button>
</div>
```

with this *CSS*

```
.no-style{
    display:inline;
}

.container > button {
    background:skyblue;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MTnM/)

But if your not worried about browser compatability you can use

```
button:not(:nth-child(3)){
   background:skyblue;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MTnM/1/)

Comment: This is the best solution especially if you are dealing with corporate users, most of which will still be using IE8 (some will even be using IE& still). Although you could use javascript or jquery to select the third occurance of button and apply some css to that.

Comment: Yes plus there should be no reason why you can't use a class, thanks @jezzipin

Comment: Cross Browser solution will really help the people plays around unsupported browsers.

Comment: @Connor I can understand from our own company system why they may not be able to alter their original html to use a class but then again if they are in that situation it is also unlikely they will be able to achieve cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: well if they can't add a class to the html then surely the can use `Element.className += ' no-style';` if not then css3 it is

Comment: I mean that their HTML may be auto-generated by something else like PHP or PL/SQL(in our case) meaning they wouldn't be able to add a new javascript file in either. Luckily I don't think that's the case in this situation.

Comment: It's what I sometimes have to deal with daily although I've found ways around it in our system!

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the HTML or the CSS stylesheet, you can try this jQuery (untested):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var buttons = $('button');
    var styles = {'width': 'auto', 'height': 'auto', 'background': 'none', 'box-shadow': ''}; 
    buttons[2].css(styles);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS pseudo clsses may help you. More info on nth child pseudo class can be obtained from [Click Here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

```
button:nth-child(3) {

  // Your CSS Here
}
```

Comment: <Comments removed>. The comments are not here for arguing which answer is better or more useful based on the specifics of each answer. If you found an answer to be useful or not useful, upvote or downvote it accordingly.